# Group by name with their id's

Tags: ruby-on-rails, group-by

How can I order it by the name of the transport and not by its id?

**order/index.haml**

```
=line_chart current_user
              .orders
              .group(:transport_id)
              .group_by_day(:created_at)
              .count,
            download: "boom"
```

*relations*

**order.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :transport
```

**transport.rb**

```
has_many :orders
```

This is the library with which I generate the graphic: https://www.chartkick.com/

Thanks!

Comment: please provide active record relation between the model

Answer (score 1):

```
current_user.orders.joins(:transports).group(:transport_id).group_by_day(:created_at).order(transports::name).count
```

hope this will work.

with this query it will generate the query with order by `transport{name}`

Comment: get the following error: `undefined local variable or method `transports'`